# Changing "and" word in authors names of polish article for "," (comma separator)

Tags: two-column, punctuation, article

The problem looks simple (but probably is not). I need to change word "and" for simple comma separator (,) in the part related with authors names. I would like to not change the "layout", but find tricky way to just change it as I mentioned above. I marked the part which is related with problem, using %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps,physrev,showkeys,twocolumn,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-2}  
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,hyperfootnotes=true,breaklinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\providecommand{\keywordsname}{Słowa kluczowe}
\providecommand{\keywords}{}
\renewcommand{\keywords}[2][]{%
\small\centering
\textbf{\keywordsname:} #2\par
}



\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}} 
\newcommand{\black}{\color{black}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\MojLinkZero}[3][black]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\MojLinkJeden}[3][magenta]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\MojLinkDwa}[3][purple]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\MojLinkTrzy}[3][brown]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\MojLinkCztery}[3][red]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}




\begin{document}

\title{This is my example of article, \linebreak[3] I need some help} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author{This is author no. 1}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\thanks{\hspace{.75mm}\MojLinkZero{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{0000-0000-0000-0000}} 
\email{mail4author1@uni.edu}
\author{This is author no. 2}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\thanks{\hspace{.75mm}\MojLinkZero{https://orcid.org/000c-0000-0000-0000}{000c-0000-0000-0000}} 
\email{mail4author2@uni.edu} 

\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}


\affiliation{Affiliation Location in Random City,
Department of Metallurgy,
Some Random Place and Street, Poland} 

\begin{abstract}
\small{Here will be abstract and some basic information, the problem is related with part above – I cannot change "and"~in authors names for comma (,). Please help}

\end{abstract}

\date[]{\today}


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue

```
\renewcommand{\andname}{\unskip,}
```

in the document preamble.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. You saved my day, thank you :)